# How to Run Python from Web Server

Tags: python-3.x, server

Currently on a side project that scrapes data from my website, and puts the data in a google spreadsheet. I would want to run this automatically, say every week. My idea is to host it in my server and have it run automatically since I might not always be able to access my computer and having it run automatically would be more convenient. Is there a way to do this? I'm relatively a beginner so please be a bit considerate. :) Thanks!

Comment: When you say "server", what OS do you have? Do you have administrative privileges there?

Comment: If u have the server, Google cron job

Comment: @Amadan what do you mean? The server my host is using or my work coumpter's OS?

Comment: Server OS, and root/admin privileges there, if you intend to execute things on it. Your work computer OS if that's where you want to execute things.

Comment: @Amadan the OS, according to the hosting provider is CENTOS. A quick Google search tells me that it's a A free rebuild of source packages from the Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cron`. [Here](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-autotasks.html) is CENTOS tutorial on `cron`. Basically, use `crontab -e` to edit your task schedule. This will open an editor; you can add new jobs as single lines. If you add a line like this:

```
0 3 * * 6 /usr/bin/python /home/johndoe/scripts/weekly.py
```

it will execute `/home/johndoe/scripts/weekly.py` every Saturday at 3am. If you don't feel like figuring out `crontab` syntax (which I recommend you do anyway), you can use any of the online crontab generators (such as [this one](http://crontab-generator.org/)).

Comment: I will take a look at this and try it out and I'll comment if I have any other questions! Thanks!

Comment: Hello! I took a look at my CPanel and found a cron feature. It looks [like this](http://i.imgur.com/xm0NRxm.png). It's there any chance this makes my life easier?

Comment: Yeah, it's just an interface to set the crontab.

Comment: So, basing from you instructed in the answer, I would just only add /usr/bin/python /home/johndoe/scripts/weekly.py to the "command" input box and then upload my python file in the specified location?

Comment: ...and set the times (hour, minute and weekday).

Comment: Got that covered ;) Last question, is there a specific folder where I need to upload the file? Or anywhere in my public_html folder? (or anywhere in myserver really?)

Comment: Doesn't matter. `cron` just runs the command you give it at time you give it. Now, whether the script itself is sensitive to where it's located is a question that is independent from `cron`.

Comment: I see! How about the modules I used in the python scripts? How are they gonna run? Do I need to do something to make them work?

Comment: Design your code so you can run it from command line using `/usr/bin/python /home/johndoe/scripts/weekly.py` regardless of which directory you're in. If it executes from the command line, then probability is high it will also execute from `cron`.

Comment: How can I make check if it runs using the command line? Sorry I'm still learning ;(

Comment: Easiest would be to develop your script on the server, using SSH access.

Comment: thanks! Can you point me to where to start reading about developing the script on the server side? Tried running the cron but it said one module does not exist :)

Comment: Sorry, can't; that's a bit outside the scope of this, and I don't even know if your host allows it. But as long as you take precautions in your Python to teach it about correct `sys.path`, you can just write (hopefully) correct code and then plunk it down onto the server.

Comment: Thanks anyway! You've been very helpful!